# What's the derivative of order 2013 of $f(x)=\frac{x^5}{1+x^6}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

What's the derivative of order 2013 of $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=\frac{x^5}{1+x^6}$ at the point 0? This question seems really difficult to solve directly, I need some others ideas how to solve it.

I need help!

thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this what was asked? The usual first question on this sort of thing is about the $n$-th derivative **at** $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you

Comment: @user: That makes the problem a lot easier, since you can use the Taylor series to find the derivative!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** The Maclaurin series expansion of $\dfrac{1}{1+x^6}$ is
$$1-x^6 +x^{12}-x^{18}+x^{24}-x^{30}+ \cdots.$$
Multiply by $x^5$. Now you have the Maclaurin series expansion of your function.

If you know the derivatives at $x=0$, then you know the Maclaurin series expansion. So if you know the Maclaurin series expansion $\dots$.

Note that $2013$ is not of the form $6k+5$, making the calculation particularly easy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very simple, beautiful and helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. Very often, we obtain the Taylor series for a function not by going back to the definition, but by manipulating (adding, differentiating, integrating) known series. Indirectly, this yields results about higher derivatives at $x=0$. That technique is widely used in combinatorics (generating functions).

Answer (score 3):

This function $f$ is the product of two functions $x \mapsto x^5$ and $x \mapsto (1 + x^6)^{-1}$. Then you can use the formula $$(fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{i=0}^n \mathrm C_n^i f^{(i)}g^{(n-i)}$$

Comment: how can I find the demonstration of this formula?

Comment: The proof is easy by induction.

Comment: I fail to see how this helps (but 4 upvoters probably know better) since the successive derivatives of $x\mapsto1/(1+x^6)$ are not easier to compute than the OP, are they?

Comment: @Did Initially the question asked for simply the derivative, rather than the derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I already know that. And this answer is supposed to help the reader to compute the derivative? Sorry but I fail to see how.

Comment: @Did I'll be honest, I'm not sure why it has been up-voted so highly. I think Damien might have been trying to make the OP realise they were missing part of the question, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^{5}}{1+x^{6}}=x^{5}(1+x^{6})^{-1}=x^{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x^{6})^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}x^{6n+5}=x^{5}-x^{11}+x^{17}-\ldots$$
Differentiating this $2013$ times will decrement each power by $2013$. Only a term of degree $2013$ will contribute to this derivative at zero, because any lower powers will have been differentiated to zero as constants, and any higher powers will evaluate to zero at zero.

Does such a term exist?

**NB**: This expansion is only valid for $|x|<1$, but since the derivative is being evaluated at zero we're okay.

Comment: The question "Does such a term exist?" seems misleading to me.

Comment: In what way? The fact that there is no term of degree $2013$ directly implies that the $2013^{th}$ derivative is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The same formula defines a function on the complexes. The denominator factors into

$$x^6 + 1 = \prod_{n=0}^5 (x - \zeta^{2n+1}) $$

where $\zeta$ is a primitive 12-th root of unity, so $f(x)$ has simple poles. The residue at each pole is given by the formula

$$ g(x) = \frac{x^5}{(x^6 + 1)'} = \frac{1}{6} $$

and so we have the partial fractions decomposition

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^5 \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{x - \zeta^{2n+1}} $$

Using the formula

$$ \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \frac{1}{x-a} = (-1)^k \frac{k!}{(x-a)^{k+1}} $$

we therefore get

$$f^{(2013)}(x) = -\frac{2013!}{6} \sum_{n=0}^5 \frac{1}{(x - \zeta^{2n+1})^{2014}} $$